# SWIFT: do I have someone set a record with different text every time?

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, cloudkit, subscriptions

So I made a chatroom and when someone sends a message they also add a Subscription in my cloud kit database but the problem is there cant be more then one of the same name that is a subscription and I want them to be able to set more subscriptions then one. Here is some code:

```
    func setupCloudKitSubscription () {
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if userDefaults.boolForKey("subscribed") == false {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil)
        let subscription = CKSubscription(recordType: "Extra1", predicate: predicate, options: CKSubscriptionOptions.FiresOnRecordCreation)

        let notificationInfo = CKNotificationInfo()
        notificationInfo.alertLocalizationKey = "New Sweet"
        notificationInfo.shouldBadge = true

        subscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo

        let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase

        publicData.saveSubscription(subscription) { (subscription:CKSubscription?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            }else{
                userDefaults.setBool(true, forKey: "subscribed")
                userDefaults.synchronize()
```

You see how it says recordType: "Extra1" how can I made the "Extra1" different text every time someone makes a subscription? Thanks!

Comment: Please, don't include image of code, copy and paste the code into your question. I don't like retyping all that.

Comment: Sorry, I am editing it now.

Comment: I edited it. I would really appreciate it if you can help me now... Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not completely clear. I think what you wanted to ask is that you want the subscription to send you a different message with each notification.

You could set it to display one or more fields of the record. For doing that you should use something like this:

```
notificationInfo.alertLocalizationKey = "Response: %1$@"
notificationInfo.alertLocalizationArgs = ["responseField"]
```

Then you also need this in your Localization.Strings file.

```
"Response: %1$@" = "Response: %1$@";
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. Here is what I want to do a bit more clearly:

Comment: I want to change "Extra1" because when a new subscription is added it makes a notifications but you cant have a new subscription with the same name so everytime someone makes a new subscription instead of it being names "Extra1" I would want it to be different name everytime.

Comment: Extra1 is not the name of your subscription. It's the name of the recordtype for your susbscription. You are using a true predicate. You could create a 2nd subscription to the same recordtype as long as the predicate is different . Otherwise it will tell you that there is already a subscription. When using a true predicate you will already receive all records for recordType Extra1 You don't need an other subscription.

Comment: How do I have the "Extra1" be a random name?

Comment: How do I have the "Extra1" be a random name?

Comment: It can't be a random name. It has to be the name of one of your recordTypes. It's that recordType what will be queried.

Comment: I dont want the notification to be different everytime I want the recordtype to be different everytime (random) so that it sends a notification because you cant have two of the same name record types generated by the same person.

Comment: You do have to be aware that recordTypes are fixed. You can't create a new recordType in production. So they can't be random. You have to predefine all your recordTypes. You can think of a recordType like it's a table in a database. A subscription will query that 'table'. You have to specify for what 'table' you want a subscription. If you want data per user, then put it in the same recordType and add a field that indicates for what person that record is. Then in your subscription predicate query for that field.